# C# Visual Studio Project broken after adding "System" Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have not come across something like this, i added a folder "system" to the project
[image]

which then i rename to "mSys" or what ever and the whole project was broken, all main components lost reference ?

i get [image]
i have manually checked through the project **.sln** / **csproj** / references
and all seems to be in order, how can i fix this ?

> The type or namespace name 'Windows' does not exist in the namespace

> CS0234    The type or namespace name 'ComponentModel' does not exist in the namespace

Comment: Remove the folder from the file explorer

Comment: i have removed it, and all "using system" etc references are in all my views.
if u run it it would generate over 50errors for every single .system component that it has no idea what it is, even doe the "using systems" is recognized on top

Comment: System is existing .net assembly namespace that you almost reference in all C# files. When you added another namespace "System" then your project tries to get the other System.ComponentModel and other related classes from your new "System" namespace is what probably causing this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what happened was that the code contained within the `System` folder was also inside the `System` namespace. Then after the rename refactoring of the folder - the namespace usings were also refactored which broke the `global::System` references.

To fix that - add `using System;` at the top of each file where the issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

OK so fixed it,adding the system folder with a class inside created a Namespace called **system** again.

the `using System;` was already present at top of each file, looking it its referenced showed me the new generated class with `mShield2.System`

renaming the folder did not rename the namespace that was auto generated... manually changing it to **"mainSys"** for example fixed the issue.

Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment in the accepted answer.